# .NET: Is there a built in version of PropertyChangedEventArgs that includes the old/new value?

Tags: .net

Is there a built in version of PropertyChangedEventArgs that includes the old/new value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no new/old value tracking within the framework's PropertyChangedEventArgs. You could of course sub-class it.

As an exercise though, you might like to implement an adapter that works with `INotifyPropertyChanged` in conjunction with `INotifyPropertyChanging` to capture the before/after values and send them on that way.

In WPF, the norm is for dependency properties to raise their change notifications with new/old values though.

Answer (score 2):

In non-WPF, there's not. You could subclass `PropertyChangedEventArgs` and add your own extra properties, though.

I don't know about WPF. Maybe it has something different that serves a similar purpose.

Comment: That is what I intend to do, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't duplicating functionality.